# Excel VBA - How to autofill formulas from a specific row and column

Tags: vba

I have formulas from cell X14 to cell X24 (X14 = X2/W2-1 and so on until X14)

Is there a code for dragging the formulas to subsequent columns on every run of the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Basic operation: you could use the macro recorder for this code to be generated automatically

Comment: Hi Julien, I've tried this but the recorder only provides code to specific cells instead of the last column with data

Comment: OK can you be more specific? Is that the last cell in column X that is not empty? Or is data to be considered in another column?

Comment: Hi Julien, every month a new column of data will be added (from row 2 to row 13) so I need to drag the formulas (row 14 onwards) that are currently in column X across to column W, hope that makes sense

Comment: Then, please try the edited code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one code line:

```
Range("X14:X24").Formula = "=X2/W2-1"
```

Not sure I understand the meaning of "dragging the formulas to subsequent columns on every run"...

**Edited**:

If you need to process the last column having a value in the second row, please test the next code:

```
Sub PlaceRangeFormulaOnLastCol()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastC As Long
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
    lastC = sh.cells(2, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    sh.Range(sh.cells(14, lastC), sh.cells(24, lastC)).Formula = "=" & sh.cells(2, lastC).Address(0, 0) & "/W2 - 1"
End Sub
```

Comment: @Zheng Yang Chiew: Should I understand that now the last column is "X:X", next time it will be "Y:Y", "Z:Z" and so on? If yes, all the time the formula should divide the the new column to "W:W" and decrease 1? I mean, the column to be processed will be the last one having a value on the second row. Should be this understanding correct?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, yes that is correct. Every month, a new set of data will populated in each column from X to Y to Z. The rows 14 to 24 are measuring the month on month change. So in the current month, the formula is X2/W2 -1, but in the next month, it will be Y2/X2 -1. Hope this makes more sense, thanks